# Kafkaesque question closure(s)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, close-reasons

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135015/is-the-rectangular-function-a-convolution-of-l1-functions/) seems about to be closed (4 votes currently), because it is (supposedly) "not about math as defined in the help center."

Can anyone explain this to me (if there is an explanation)? I find it mind-boggling. I would say the quality of the question places it very clearly in the top 1% of the site, as a conservative estimate.

PS: I happen to have answered this question, but that's not the reason I'm posting here. Rather, it's the other way around, if I hadn't answered it, I probably wouldn't be aware of the impending closure.

**Added later:** Thanks to all who attempted to clarify. I do not wish to get involved in any further discussion of this topic at this point, for several reasons, and maybe just one of them can serve as an illustration:

I asked my only question ever on MSE almost exactly 5 years ago, and it led a peaceful existence until yesterday, when all of a sudden it collects 3 close votes and 1 downvote.

Now of course this is so ridiculously childish that one shouldn't take it seriously, and one could even get some entertainment value out of it, but if this is how things are handled on MSE, then it's clearly not the kind of enterprise or activity I want to be a part of.

**Added later still:** Derek's theory in the comments below deserves praise for its good intentions, but it doesn't match the facts. The close "reason" given in the 3 original close votes was that the question was "too broad."
Then apparently someone (rschwieb ?) felt compelled to investigate if more convincing close reasons could be found, and (what a stroke of luck, that!) it turns out that the same question was also asked by someone else. Sure enough, my question is closed now as a "duplicate." Never mind that the other question came later.

All of which is perfectly fine with me; I was feeling slightly embarrassed about the question anyway and would have deleted it if that had been possible. I do advise against further attempts to explain any of this, though.

Comment: Mysterious? In all likelihood, because it is just a problem statement, which as you know we typically close for improvement.  If you click through past the reason you saw to the sub-menu, it details everyone voted for this reason: "This question is missing context or other details"

Comment: May I ask, what exactly are you basing your assessment of the question quality? Beyond being properly grammatical and typeset, there isn't much in the way that differentiates it from [a question like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3145296/29335).  I suppose one could certainly like the question itself, but that isn't really an objective measure of quality.

Comment: I should also add that (as I have mentioned in previous discussions) some of us (at least me) don't come down as hard on example/counterexample questions if they are actually involved and hard, because it can be challenging to provide context. But as for the topic at hand (why people voted to close) we can say with some certainty what the sentiment was.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what there is to praise?

Comment: At the present moment, the question is closed, but has four votes to reopen.

Comment: It's no longer closed, and I would personally not close it since it seems to be purely out of curiosity, but there are two points you should take note: (1) As quid already said in his answer, good questions as per [the how-to-ask page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will almost surely be well-received, and certainly be preferable to what the current question is right now (a bare question).

Comment: (2) The close-reason shown may not be the reason that all close-voters picked; those who picked it are listed at the end. Anyway the right reason would be "Off-topic: This question is missing context or other details" and not "Off-topic: This question is not about mathematics".

Comment: Last call for what there is to praise about the question before I give up asking.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Since you say that it is *obviously* interesting, perhaps you might be able to add at least few sentences to the post explaining why the question is interesting or what it is related to. Or at least suggest to the OP what they might add to the question. (I am aware that some users object to somebody else than the OP editing context into the question, but maybe it is at least worth trying.) In the current form, it seems likely to continue the close/reopen (possibly delete/undeleted) cycle, especially after the additional attention that this question received from meta.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Your question was 1) unanswered, and 2) closed *as duplicate*. You don't lose any reputation by having a question closed. You only lose reputation when a question is deleted which usually *doesn't* happen for duplicates. There is also no particular value judgment related to a question being closed as a duplicate. Once there is a recent close vote on a question, it enters review queues. At that point many people will see it regardless of whether they are aware of this Meta question.

Comment: All told, 1) your question was probably noticed by someone who was active in this thread, but 2) most of the people who then interacted with it were probably unaware of this Meta question. Further, 3) closing as duplicate has no reputational cost to you, and 4) is actually the correct thing to do in this case. While you probably aren't still interested in the answer to that question, it now has one where it didn't before and there is one less unanswered question on the site.

Comment: This was very unlikely to be some kind of coordinated campaign against you and is rather weak sauce as a "retaliation" (though still unacceptable if that was what it was). It's quite possible that the only reputation affecting part, the downvote, was by someone who was unaware of this Meta question.

Comment: @ChristianRemling The additional facts only *support* my "theory". As I stated, once you got *one* close vote, your question enters the review queues and is viewed by anyone looking at the review queues. If the three people who close voted as too broad were "retaliating", you'd have *three* downvotes, not one. If someone was trying to attack your reputation, closing as duplicate is about the worst possible way to do that. Being closed as too broad likely would lead to deletion eventually. The facts suggest that there was at most one, very incompetent, user "retaliating" against you.

Comment: @DerekElkins Pre-merge, Christian's question was answered by gt6989b (but it was moved to the other after the merge, making it look unanswered.) . But what you said is still basically the same: the other question had more answers and comments. All other things being equal, it seemed sensible to merge in the direction that occurred.

Comment: Dear @ChristianRemling : Don't worry friend: in the future if you write more questions and I find one about to be closed for reasons that might get them deleted, I will not bother trying to preserve them even as duplicates or merges, since you apparently prefer to take your chances with the ones that wanted it to go away completely.

Comment: Also FWIW the timestamp between duplicate questions is usually immaterial when deciding which one should be closed. Usually weight is given to the qualities of the question posed, the answers, the comments, and so on.

Comment: Hi! I am the OP in the question mentioned here. When asking the question I hesitated between MathOverflow and math.stackexchange and opted for the latter as it didn't look like research-level to me. I am really puzzled about the open/close cycle that followed. I tried to formulate the question in a short and simple way. If somebody feels that the question does not respect the standards, please go ahead and edit, as I really don't see what to do.

Comment: More important: I was really happy by the answers I received, all of them being highly interesting. I commented to each answer to thank and share my joy of learning great mathematics. For some obscure reason these comments have been deleted. Let me take this opportunity to thank again all people who took the time to answer my question.

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun The comments are deleted because they are not deemed productive by MSE and routinely removed by computer. See [Why do we need to avoid to thank somebody?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23549/why-do-we-need-to-avoid-to-thank-somebody/) and [showing gratitude for a very helpful/detailed answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29929/showing-gratitude-for-a-very-helpful-detailed-answer) for related discussion.

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun As Quid's answer here points out, the reason for the closure(s) were that a question without some sort of context (or possibly "motivation" is more relevant here) is not a good question. It is not just about formulating the question in a "short and simple way". (I was one of the original 5 vote-to-close people, and this was my reason. Going by the closure reason ("off topic"), most of the other close-voters had a similar reason.)

Comment: (I do not know the reason for the repeated reopening. I guess being on +11 sways peoples opinions. I guess also this meta-question increases visibility, which means more people want to voice their opinion by voting one way or the other.)

Comment: @user1729: What happens is simply that, as opposed to the concerted closing of questions, there is no concerted effort to keep open and/or reopen closed questions. So questions like this are mostly saved by visibility on meta, where many of us learn about the closure and disagree with it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I agree, and have pondered such a concerted effort before. But I'm too busy with life to organise such a thing! :-)

Comment: I think we should allow duplicates, it's just storage! 

Comment: @MartinSleziak (or other) do you by chance have a link to ChristianRemling's question, closed as duplicate of a later one?

Comment: @YCor I think that the question to which this post refers is: [Mathematical intro to Turing machines](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/729583).It was [merged with another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/729583/revisions) by a moderator.

Answer (score 10):

The "off-topic" menu contains some sub-points most notably this:

> This question is missing context or other details: Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

I assume this will at least somewhat clear up the confusion. Now, some would still argue that there is nothing missing there, but some others do insist that more is required in a question post. Details of information that should be provided are given each there: [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) especially the answer on context.

Comment: That's a discussion that we had often. I won't contest that it is obviously interesting for some. But, I'll say this: obviously it could be made more interesting and accessible for many if more information was provided. If things were spelled out a bit more, at least the question would be essentially completely understandable for every calculus student at least. I don't see why we should not insist on higher standards for presentation.

Comment: Just to be clear regarding the previous comment: are you suggesting the question should have given a reference for how $L^1(\mathbb R)$ is defined and how convolution is defined on $L^1(\mathbb R)$? (I am not objecting, I just want to be clear about what needs to be spelled out in this particular question.)

Comment: @Dap yes, that's what I had in mind. I am sure it's not the only way to contextualize the question. But when it already is presented as a bare and seemingly ad hoc problem, one might as well  brake further it down to a question about an integral.

Comment: Anyone is free to dislike (read vote down) a question if it does not define standard terms that the voter in question happens to not know, and unable to google. But that is a terribly reason for closing a question. The fact that this *might* be a homework question is also not a reason to close it, since one might as well shut down the whole site if that criterion were strictly applied.

Comment: @AlexB. "But that is a terribly reason for closing a question." Alright that's your opinion. Any more detailed thought on this. It's not as if this was not discussed any number of times already.

Comment: "The fact that this might be a homework question is also not a reason to close it [...]"  Did anyone say it was closed for that reasons specifically? In any case, I did not.

Comment: One more point so that this does not get misunderstood @AlexB., the issue is not over the voter(s) not knowing or being unable to look up a term, it is about the quality of the presentation being lacking. This is a reason for closure on this site, as it is a reason for rejection or requests for revision at most any scholarly journal, for example. Depending on the instructor also for homework, term papers, etc.  It's not very clear to me why that's so difficult to accept as it's perfectly common.

Comment: I do not submit to journals that reject papers for failing to define standard terms that every researcher in the area can be expected to know (and all the words used the in the post in question do indeed fall into this category). I will not argue about "most any scholarly journal", because I do not care what "most any scholarly journal" does. I do not like the tone of "It's not very clear to me why that's so difficult to accept as it's perfectly common", so I will now withdraw from this discussion.